# Google font not showing in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, google-font-api

for my website I'm using couple of google fonts:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,300italic,400italic&subset=latin,latin-ext);

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
```

The work well in Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox (I tried 47 and 47.0.1) the font "Montserrat" is not displaied.

It's very curious because I get no network error or no other error in the console and only one is not working, the other one is working fine.

Do you know any solutions?
Thanks!

Comment: This is working fine for me in Firefox: https://jsfiddle.net/6vb6pjz4/

Comment: Keep reloading the page. After a few time it may work OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you guys were pointing out the code I posted works on Firefox. The problem was that the font-family was override by another css (still don't know why this was happening only in Firefox...). I just created this class:

```
.font-montserrat {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

And just added:

```
.font-montserrat {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;
}
```

Now the font is properly rendered in every browser!

Comment: This didn't work for me. In my case, my laptop had Montserrat installed. Firefox was using this. I deleted it. Firefox then started using the font downloaded from googleapis.com and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too. I did however load the google font in a link tag. The following worked for me, but I am not sure why.

Originally my link tag looked like this (didn't work in Firefox):

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400' />
```

It did however work when I removed the 'https:'. Like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400' />
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use Fonts from Google Fonts, you don't need to use `@font-face` at all. Use those fonts through classes if you want, like this:

**CSS**

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,300italic,400italic&subset=latin,latin-ext);

.font-montserrat {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.font-raleway {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p class="font-montserrat">This is Montserrat</p>
<p class="font-raleway">This is Raleway</p>
```

When you write `font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif` after `font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif` it will just override the font Montserrat with Raleway so that's why instead of Montserrat you will see Raleway.