# My font from Google Fonts won't show up on my website anymore

Tags: javascript, css, google-font-api

I am building a web application and using Google Fonts for my two main fonts. Both fonts were working perfectly and then randomly one began to not show up. I've tried clearing my cache and reverting a couple git commits to see if I inadvertently commited something that messed it up. Neither of these solutions worked.

My CSS link is:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|Roboto+Condensed:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
```

Pacifico is the font that fails. I'm able to access that URL and the URL that the resulting CSS points to: https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pacifico/v13/FwZY7-Qmy14u9lezJ-6I6MmTpA.woff2, which begins downloading the font. However, on the network monitor on Firefox, there isn't any activity on the Pacifico URL, only the Roboto-Condensed URL.

Comment: are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @I'mOnlyVueman No reported errors in the console.

Comment: You may try using a css import instead of the html cdn, just click the import option on the font's website and it'll show you the css syntax for importing. If that doesn't work, maybe doing separate import for pacifico and the other fonts

Comment: Have you tried another modern browser?

Comment: Keep in mind that you may only see the font loaded in your network if you actually have elements on the page that are using that font; inspect the elements that are not rendering the expected font, and double check that the CSS is applying the correct font-family rule to them

Comment: @BlakeMann The CSS is being applied correctly

Comment: Inspect the element that is supposed to have the font and be sure that the font-family is set appropriately. Also make sure you haven't overridden the font-family later in the document.

Comment: @isherwood I should have tried that sooner, but I can confirm it works in Chromium, but not in Firefox. However, it was working in Firefox previously.

Answer (score 0):

This should have been something I tried earlier, but it just seemed like too simple of solution.

The problem was fixed by restarting Firefox. The browser must have had a random glitch that caused the failure.

Comment: If that fix proves temporary, try removing the protocol: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49100488/1264804